# Change specific characters in just part of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to change a specific in text, so I need to find all ";" characters and change them to "$" but only if they are in bracket(s).

So, there can be few cases:

example 1
text (it's ok; it's not ok); ok
should be:
text (it's ok$ it's not ok); ok

example 2
text (it's ok; it's not ok); ok (tekst;) ok
should be:
text (it's ok$ it's not ok); ok (tekst$) ok

example 3
text (it's ok; (ok;)it's not ok);
should be:
text (it's ok$ (ok$)it's not ok);

so I've started with replacing strings code, but problem is that my code now replace characters even after ")" and I don't want that.

should I somehow counts string that need to be changed and set start position and change only them? But then problem is if we have more brackets, it will not work.

what would be best way to do it?

```
Sub Removetext()
s = Range("A1").Value

Dim start As Integer
Dim end1 As Integer
start = InStr(1, s, "(")
end1 = InStr(1, s, ")")

s = Left(s, start - 1) & Replace(s, ";", "$", start)

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to look into regular expressions but if you don't want to get into all that, you could loop through each character and keep track of the positions of left brackets, right brackets and semi-colons and use the Characters property.

Comment: I have added `regex` tag just so that somebody may assist with it.

Comment: There is no reason to use a regex tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, avoiding regexp as I don't use it enough to be able to remember how to do it without a lot of effort.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, lb As Long, rb As Long, r As Range

Range("A1:A4").Copy Range("B1")

For Each r In Range("B1:B4")
    For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = "(" Then lb = lb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ")" Then rb = rb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ";" Then
            If lb > 0 And rb < lb Then r.Characters(i, 1).Text = "$"
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It misses the edge case of a `;` outside of a parenthesis inside a parenthesis like `((;)ok;)`. If that's a problem.

Comment: This looks great, only problem is what @ChristoferWeber said, if we have case: (it's ok; (ok;)it's not; ok); in part "it's not;" should be "it's not$" so whenever we are in any open parenthesis switch should be activated

Comment: Yes missed that. Will your text otherwise follow normal rules, i.e. brackets will always go in pairs, left then right?

Comment: I've amended the code above, can you give it another try?

Comment: this update is working as it should. Yes, text will follow normal rules, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Replace Between Chars (UDF)

- If there are more occurrences of `LeftChar` (opening parentheses) than of `RightChar` (closing parentheses) to the left of
  `FindChar`, `FindChar` will be replaced with `ReplaceChar`.
- In `Excel`, for a string in `A1` you can use it like this:

  `=RBC(A1)`
- In `VBA` see below.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function RBC( _
    ByVal aString As String, _
    Optional ByVal LeftChar As String = "(", _
    Optional ByVal RightChar As String = ")", _
    Optional ByVal FindChar As String = ";", _
    Optional ByVal ReplaceChar As String = "$") _
As String
    
    If Len(aString) > 0 Then
        
        Dim Parts() As String
        Parts = Split(aString, FindChar)
        Dim Result As String
        Result = Parts(0)
        
        Dim cLen As Long
        Dim lCount As Long
        Dim rCount As Long
        Dim n As Long
        
        For n = 1 To UBound(Parts)
            cLen = Len(Result)
            lCount = cLen - Len(Replace(Result, LeftChar, ""))
            rCount = cLen - Len(Replace(Result, RightChar, ""))
            If lCount > rCount Then
                Result = Result & ReplaceChar & Parts(n)
            Else
                Result = Result & FindChar & Parts(n)
            End If
        Next n
        
        RBC = Result
    
    End If
    
End Function

Sub testRBC()
    Const aString As String = "(it's ok; (ok;)it's not; ok);"
    Debug.Print RBC(aString)
End Sub

' Results in column B:
Sub testRBC2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100000")
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(i, 1) = RBC(Data(i, 1))
    Next i
    rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Data
End Sub
```